# Define output range of filter() function

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am using the `filter()` function in Excel and would like to alter the output range to only return it vertically.

In a separate sheet, I have two columns. One column returns a person’s payment, and the next column returns the date of the payment (I also have a third column for ID number on the person which is used in the filter function, but this is not outputted).

My sheet filters payments within a given month. If there is only one match (*e.g. 100 paid on 01/01/2010*), it works fine and will return

```
100
01/01/2010
```

The output is like this due to the use of `transpose()`. However, if there are more than one match it will return the following:

```
100         500
01/01/2010      01/20/2019
```

My aim is to have it outputted all vertically like this:

```
100
01/01/2010
500
01/20/2019
```

How do I achieve to have it outputted as demonstrated above? I imagine that it is possible to write a user defined function in VBA that assigns each output element and then define in the function to output it vertically – but I do not know how to approach such a code.

Sheet1 contains the data as follows:

```
Payments    Date            ID_no
100         01/01/2010      ID01
500         01/20/2019      ID01
```

My `filter()` function is demonstrated below

`TRANSPOSE(FILTER(Sheet1!Z2:AA13;(Sheet1!AB2:AB13=B1)*(Sheet1!AA2:AA13>S4)*(Sheet1!AA2:AA13<=T4);"")`) where

`Sheet1!Z2:AA13` is the two columns with payment and date of payment

`Sheet1!AB2:AB13=B1` is that the ID column must equal the ID written in cell B1

`Sheet1!AA2:AA13>S4` is that the date of payment must be above (after) the date written in S4

`Sheet1!AA2:AA13<=T4` is that the date must be below (before) the date written in T4

The two latter ensures that only payments within a specific time frame (one month) is included.
Be aware that payments are made no more than three times during a month i.e. the output range will not be longer than 6 (3x2) rows.

**The ideal end result** is a user defined function that in principle is the same as the above `filter()` but redefines where to output so it is only outputted vertically i.e. if the function is typed in column A the output of the function should only be in column A

Link to file https://wetransfer.com/downloads/c3a081f47e20fd1718510545f9a7b80820200627212111/8eeb4f

Comment: Were would you like the result to be output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the next function, please. Since you did not answer my question regarding the result outputting, it will be dropped in the last sheet empty column:

```
Function PaymentReturn(strID As String, sh As Worksheet) As Variant
  Dim lastRow As Long, arr As Variant, arrFin As Variant
  Dim i As Long, k As Long

  lastRow = sh.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
  arr = sh.Range("A2:C" & lastRow).Value
  ReDim arrFin(UBound(arr, 1))
  For i = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
    If arr(i, 3) = strID Then
        arrFin(k) = arr(i, 1): k = k + 1
        arrFin(k) = arr(i, 2): k = k + 1
    End If
  Next i
  ReDim Preserve arrFin(k - 1)
  PaymentReturn = arrFin
End Function
```

The function can be called in the next way:

```
Sub testFuncPaym()
   Dim sh As Worksheet, lastEmptyCol As Long, arr As Variant, strID As String
   
   strID = "ID02" 'ID to be returned
   Set sh = ActiveSheet 'use here your sheet to be processed
   lastEmptyCol = sh.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
   arr = PaymentReturn(strID, sh)

   sh.Cells(1, lastEmptyCol).Value = "Output"
   sh.Cells(2, lastEmptyCol).Resize(UBound(arr) + 1, 1) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arr)
End Sub
```

Comment: @Lasse T.: Still alive? Did you find some time to test the above code? If yes, does it what you need?

Comment: FaneDuru, apologies for the late response.

As I am not that experienced with VBA, can you provide some additional comments as to how it should be executed? 

Now, my 'active sheet' that contains the filter() functions, I have a filter function in each column which then returns payment made within a specific month based on a row that contains dates with one month between each date. Thus, I imagine it would be  trivial to execute the VBA for each month? In particular when I introduce new sheets with new ID numbers? 

I would appreciate comments to your code, but see my updated my question

Comment: @Lasse T.:  I do not understand too much from your request... I clearly stated "The function can be called in the next way:". What is not clear in the code following the above sentance? You must call the above function as I have shown: `arr = PaymentReturn(strID, sh)`. I asked you where to return the processed data, but **you did not answer anything**. So, I announced that the function output **will be dropped in the last sheet empty column**. Is it something unclear in this statement?

Comment: FaneDuru, allow me to take a further look at your code, and I will get back to you. 

The return of the data should be placed from

    `ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select` to

    `ActiveCell.Offset(5, 0).Range("A1").Select`

If you get what I mean?

Feel free to take a look at the file where you will see how my own function works nicely in column T, but in column it becomes an issue because there is also output in column V (which is not desired). There is a link to the file in the updated question

Comment: @Lasse T.: I did not see any code in your question, when made the code and neither a link to something. I did not see a piece of code neither now. It is not wise to download workbooks from unknown sources. Now I am busy. If I will have time to look at your workbook, I will maybe take the risk to download it and see what it is about. But, you must learn how a question must be asked... Nobody wants wasting his time for unclear questions. I did it for specific circumstances making assumptions. If you are not able to use the solution for your code, I will maybe help, but not know.

Comment: I think your code will allow me to achieve what I want. Thanks!
[link to file](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/c3a081f47e20fd1718510545f9a7b80820200627212111/8eeb4f)